# How to select if any part of an array is contained in an array column in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table in Postgres that looks like this:

```
ROW    Fruit
----   -----
1.     {"Candied Apples" , "Oranges"}
2.     {"Oranges"}
3.     {"Granny Smith Apples"}
```

I am able to get row #3 that has "Granny Smith Apples" using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Fruit @> '{"Granny Smith Apples"}';
```

What I need to do now is do an array compare, if any of my array is found in the column, I want to return that row.

I tried:

```
SELECT *  mytable WHERE Fruit @> ANY('{"Oranges","Granny Smith Apples"}');
```

...and I get back no results.  I also tried 'has elements in common', but that's still only giving me back row 2 and not row 1?

```
SELECT *  mytable WHERE Fruit && '{"Oranges","Granny Smith Apples"}';
```

I also tried searching for a single value in the array, and that doesn't work either:

```
SELECT *  mytable WHERE Fruit @> ANY('{"Oranges"}');
```

I get back 0 results.  It only seems to work if I am checking a single value against an array with only 1 value in it - an exact match.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The query with the `&&` works for me and returns all rows: http://rextester.com/SNB38571

Comment: I have another column with a space inbetween the values that did the same thing. I removed the space, and now it works fine.  Maybe a weirdness with psycopg2?

Answer (score 0):

Arg. I had a space in the column, and once I fixed that it worked fine.

From this:

```
ROW    Fruit
----   -----
1.     {"Candied Apples" , "Oranges"}
2.     {"Oranges"}
3.     {"Granny Smith Apples"}
```

To this:

```
ROW    Fruit
----   -----
1.     {"Candied Apples","Oranges"}
2.     {"Oranges"}
3.     {"Granny Smith Apples"}
```

Comment: `{"Candied Apples" , "Oranges"}` and `{"Candied Apples","Oranges"}` are identical arrays: http://rextester.com/DSQP92237 there must be something else going on